# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk without Git

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a nodejs application to Amazon EC2 using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk console. We have a custom repository manager and are not using Git. Is Git a prerequisite for using Beanstalk? Or can I use it with any version manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a node.js container and upload it to your Elastic Beanstalk application instance as a zip file. You have to make sure your zip file contains the .ebextentions folder with all the required configuration.

You can find more information about the configuration of a node.js container here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_custom_container.html

and here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#command-options-nodejs

Also, you can check out this blog on how to deploy "Ghost" (A node.js based blog) to Elastic Beanstalk by uploading the zip file:

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx37ALIK2KLNIVC/Six-Steps-to-Deploy-Ghost-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use git to push your application bundle into Elastic Beanstalk. You can upload your bundle to an S3 bucket, then using either the [eb command line](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-api-cli.html), or the [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/index.html), first create an "application version" that points to that bundle, then update your environment with that version.

The relevant documentation for the eb command line:

- [create-application-version](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/CLIReference-cmd-CreateApplicationVersion.html)
- [update-environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/CLIReference-cmd-UpdateEnvironment.html)

And for the AWS CLI:

- [create-application-version](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/create-application-version.html)
- [update-environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/update-environment.html)